# Error including a column in a join between spark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a join between **`cleanDF`** and **`sentiment_df`** using `array_contains` that works fine ([from solution 61687997](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61687997/calculate-new-column-in-spark-dataframe-crossing-a-tokens-list-column-in-df1-wi)). And I need include in the **`Result`** df a new column ('Year') from **`cleanDF`**.

This is the join:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

Result = cleanDF.join(sentiment_df, expr("""array_contains(MeaningfulWords,word)"""), how='left')\
                .groupBy("ID")\
                .agg(first("MeaningfulWords").alias("MeaningfulWords")\
                  ,collect_list("score").alias("ScoreList")\
                  ,mean("score").alias("MeanScore"))
```

This is the **`Result`** structure:

```
Result.show(5)

#+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
#|                ID|     MeaningfulWords|           ScoreList|        MeanScore|
#+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
#|a0U3Y00000p1IzjUAE|[buen, servicio, ...|        [6.39, 1.82]|            4.105|
#|a0U3Y00000p1KhGUAU|              [mala]|              [2.02]|             2.02|
#|a0U3Y00000p1M1oUAE|[cliente, content...|        [6.39, 8.41]|              7.4|
#|a0U3Y00000p1OnTUAU|[positivo, trato,...|               [8.2]|             8.19|
#|a0U3Y00000p1R5DUAU|[momento, sido, g...|               [6.0]|              6.0|
#+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

I add a `.select` ([36132322](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132322/join-two-data-frames-select-all-columns-from-one-and-some-columns-from-the-othe)) to include the column **`Year`** from **`cleanDF`**:

```
Result1 = cleanDF.alias('a').join(sentiment_df.alias('b'), expr("""array_contains(a.MeaningfulWords,b.word)"""), how='left')\
                .select(col('a.ID'),col('a.Year'),col('a.MeaningfulWords'),col('b.word'),col('b.score'))\
                .groupBy("ID")\
                .agg(first("a.MeaningfulWords").alias("MeaningfulWords")\
                  ,collect_list("score").alias("ScoreList")\
                  ,mean("score").alias("MeanScore"))
```

But I get in **`Result1`** the same columns than `**Result**`:

```
display(Result1)

#DataFrame[ID: string, MeaningfulWords: array<string>, ScoreList: array<double>, MeanScore: double]
```

When I'm try include **`Year`** in `.agg` function:

```
Result2 = cleanDF.join(sentiment_df, expr("""array_contains(MeaningfulWords,word)"""), how='left')\
                .groupBy("ID")\
                .agg(first("MeaningfulWords").alias("MeaningfulWords"),first("Year").alias("Year")\
                  ,collect_list("score").alias("ScoreList")\
                  ,mean("score").alias("MeanScore"))

Result2.show()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3205.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec.doExecute(BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec.scala:343)
    ...
    ...
    ...
        Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1066)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:107)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1063)
    ...
    ...
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 411.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 411.0 (TID 9719, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$5: (array<string>) => array<string>)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1066)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SimpleHigherOrderFunction$class.eval(higherOrderFunctions.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ArrayFilter.eval(higherOrderFunctions.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    ...
    ...
    ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Im using pyspark on spark 2.4.5.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: From the exception, I can see issue is java.lang.NullPointerException, do you have that column in any one dataframe if yes, can you filter null values.. also show schema for both dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Year column might be having null values & because of that it is failing with `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` exception. Filter all null values from `Year` column.

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas, I have imputed null values in 'Year' column and then the  java.lang.NullPointerException has been resolved, and now I have the column 'Year' in Result2. Is there some alternative to include the records with null 'Year' in this join?

Comment: Instead of null, put zero or negative number.

Comment: also can you post result2 df printschema ??

Comment: Now I already have the column 'Year' in Result2 (I imputed null values to default value). This is the structure: `DataFrame[ID: string, MeaningfulWords: array<string>, Year: int, ScoreList: array<double>, MeanScore: double]`. I just have the doubt, if exist some alternative to include the rows with null 'Year' in this join, **without impute the null values**. Thanks in advance @Srinivas!